# ASP.NET Mvc does not redirect to Login page when not authorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, http-status-code-404, scaffolding

When user is not authorized i don't have a redirect to Login page..

I use scaffold identity Account\Login and Account\Register

in my StartUp class I use this code:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            //options.Cookie.Name = "YourAppCookieName";
            //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            //options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            //options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
            //options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            //// Requires `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;`
            //options.ReturnUrlParameter =
            //CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
        });
```

MyController is using [Authorize] annotation, And Index method uses [AllowAnonymous]

when I click on edit when not authorized

[image]

I get

[image]

when I need to be on Login page..

May be I forgot something?? i followed my excercixe and 100x checked it, but still got this  failure

Kind regards, ilya

Comment: what the error message says ?

Comment: You are getting "Http Error 404", confirm you have a controller named `AccountController` and inside it, you have an action method `Login(string ReturnUrl)` and of type `[HttpGet]`

Comment: So i could resolve it by adding.. endpoints.MapRazorPages(); in app.UseEndpoints